# How to extract this kind of slices in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
gt_boxes = tf.constant(np.random.rand(2, 10, 4))
gt_counts = tf.constant([3, 5])
boxes1 = tf.slice(gt_boxes, [0, 0, 0], tf.constant([1, 3, 4]))  # --> 1x3x4
boxes2 = tf.slice(gt_boxes, [1, 0, 0], tf.constant([1, 5, 4]))  # --> 1x5x4
```

Is there any way to combine the `gt_boxes` and `gt_counts` together, without the index? Or it needs a `tf.while_loop` to handle this kind of indexing. Could you please give some advice? Thanks.

Comment: I guess gt_counts means you want to first 3 boxes at the first batch and first 5 boxes at the second batch, right?

Comment: For example, you can use `boxes = tf.gather_nd(gt_boxes, [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]])` to get the first 3 boxes. So the problem is converted to how to use `gt_counts` to generate the target indices. If `gt_counts` is a list, it will be much simpler. However, if it is tensor, I haven't found an efficient to generate the target indices.

Comment: @zihaozhihao, thanks a lot for your kind comment and suggestions! Yes, the gt_counts means the valid count of boxes in each images.